# Selecting a specific row and column within pandas data array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hopefully this is a quick and simple one. Having looked through the entirity of the pandas.DataFrame documentation I can't quite seem to find exactly what I need. I have a DataFrame as:

```
           StartDate          End Date
0   10/11/2014 00:00  10/12/2014 12:00
1   12/01/2015 08:00  31/01/2015 07:59
2   15/01/2015 00:00  19/02/2015 15:43
```

Say, for example, I want to access the value at `StartDate` column index value `2`...i.e, `15/01/2015 00:00` how is this achieved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.loc[2, 'StartDate'])
15/01/2015 00:00
```

or faster [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
print (df.at[2, 'StartDate'])
15/01/2015 00:00
```

---

```
In [199]: %timeit (df.loc[2, 'StartDate'])
10000 loops, best of 3: 147 µs per loop

In [200]: %timeit (df.at[2, 'StartDate'])
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.3 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
df.loc[2, 'StartDate']
```